# python regex find match in list

Tags: python, regex, loops, conditional-statements

I have a list:

```
chain_views = [u'x|frequency|x:y|||cbase', 
               u'x|frequency|x:y||weights_UK18|cbase', 
               u'x|frequency||y|weights_UK18|c%']
```

I want to check the condition below against the list above

```
if el.startswith('x|frequency|') and el.split('|')[4]!='' and el.split('|')[3]=='y':
```

How can I convert the condition above in regex?

Right now I am checking this in a loop and I think regex would be a better option maybe?

```
for el in chain.views:

    if el.startswith('x|frequency|') and el.split('|')[4]!='' and el.split('|')[3]=='y':
        weighted_views = True
        break
    else:
        weighted_views = False

return weighted_views
```

Comment: What is the goal of that for cycle? it always returns the `weighted_views` result of the last list element right now.

Comment: Are you confusing `continue` with `break`? Continue just does the next iteration, which it would do anyway. Also you could avoid calling `el.split('|')` twice. I know it's only example code, but still worth noting.

Comment: you're right, I am confusing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the strings look like a sort of CSV, I would prefer to work with `split` function and completely avoid regex.

```
for el in chain_views:
    a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 = el.split('|')  # give better names
    if a0 == 'x' and a1 == 'frequency' and a3 == 'y' and a4:
        return True
return False
```

Answer (score 1):

if regular expressions certainly make life easier

I hope this works for you

import re

x =  [

```
u'x|frequency|x:y|||cbase',
u'x|frequency|x:y||weights_UK18|cbase',
u'x|frequency||y|weights_UK18|c%'
```

]

t = "-".join(x)+'-'

x = re.findall(r'((?:x\|\w+\|(?:x:y)?\|)(?!\|)[^-]*)+', t)

where x is your new list already filtered